# Spring LDAP | Login and get member of

Tags: java, spring, ldap, spring-ldap, spring-security-ldap

I'm starting with Spring LDAP and I am reading a lot of posts and starting to understand how this works.
What im trying to do is a standard Login. And when the login is done manage the users at the java code by their LDAP (OU)/(member of) propperty. May also get the user roles at the actual Login.

My first simple login code:

```
<authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"
class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="company.local" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://servername.company.local" />
</beans:bean>
```

Shall I use templates?

What bean id would be great to start to acomplish what i want to do?

Without LDIF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security has a [couple](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/xml/ldap) of [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/javaconfig/ldap) that demonstrate how to authenticate with LDAP as the backend. Each sample uses an embedded LDAP server for ease of demonstration, but the configuration can be changed to [point to an AD server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#activedirectoryldapauthenticationprovider). For roles, take a look at [`LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ldap-authorities).

I'm not certain what you mean by templates, but you can specify a custom `searchFilter` like so:

```
<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"
        class= "org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="company.local" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://servername.company.local" />
    <beans:property name="searchFilter" value="customUserAttribute={0}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

With the default being `(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))`.

LDIF only matters to Spring Security when you use the embedded server, which might come into play for you with integration testing.